# class cast exception in weblogic

Tags: java, exception, casting, jersey, weblogic

I have a web application (WAR file) which uses jersey jars.Now when i am trying to deploy this i am getting class cast exception(Some bootstrap servlet uses jersey)..On analysis i found that weblogic itself have jersey jars in common\modules..and my web app have different version of jersey jars. Now if i delete the common/modules jersey jar then my web app got deployed.I want to know how can i make my web app to use its own version of jersey jars so that it gets deployed without deleting common/module jars..
PS my .war file don't have weblogic.xml and weblogic is generating it on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

Get the `weblogic.xml` generated on the fly by WebLogic and modify it to add:

```
<container-descriptor>
   <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

Now make sure to have this weblogic.xml in your war file and redeploy the application.

Setting prefer-web-inf-classes to true [will give preference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1067857) to the classes present in the application's WEB-INF directory.

`prefer-web-inf-classes` may not work all the time. If you are using a WebLogic version of 10.3.4+ then use remove prefer-web-inf-classes setting and use [prefer-application-packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#autoId24) instead. Also go through [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ArLTKapjV_8#t=306s) video on how classloading in WebLogic works.

Comment: Its already have weblogic.xml and it already have above code in it..but still its not working..

Comment: Where do you have the Jersey jars in the war file? Are they under WEB-INF directory?

Comment: yes it in web inf and different  version  of jersey is present in modules dir of weblogic

Comment: which version of weblogic are you using? If you are using a 10.3.4+ then remove the prefer-web-inf element and add [prefer-application-packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#autoId24) Also take a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ArLTKapjV_8#t=306s) video which gives details on how classloading is done. I guess you redeployed the application after changing the weblogic.xml?

Comment: thanks for your help..i am using 12c ..<prefer-application-packages> is working..why is <prefer-web-inf> not working..

Comment: I am not so sure, there seems to be a bug in prefer-web-inf and it doesn't work all the time and Oracle also recommends using prefer-application-packages. They are probably still maintaining the prefer-web-inf for backporting purposes.

Comment: How do you package the war file? Some notes: The packaging build is introducing unnecessary jars? or All the jersey jars (irrespective of whether the classes being used by your application or not) are not present in web-inf there by classloading resorting to weblogic lib folder?

Comment: we are using maven builds and jersey jars are required by the web application..infact it is getting loaded on bootstrap..we are loading com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer servlet on startup...we are using jersey bundle 1.1.5 jar..while weblogic have .9 in the module folder..i guess its not possible to override module dir jars.

Comment: I stumbled upon a [Maven + WebLogic issue](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-22597.html)