# MyFaces-api not found when packed in war deployed to Weblogic 10.3

Tags: jsf, weblogic, war, jsf-1.2, myfaces

I have packed the myfaces-api.1.2.2.jar and myfaces-impl.1.2.2.jar into my war's web-inf/lib directory. If i deploy this to the weblogic 10.3 server as a zipped war file the startup log shows:

INFO: FacesConfigurator:339 - MyFaces-package : myfaces-api not found.
INFO: FacesConfigurator:339 - MyFaces-package : myfaces-impl not found.
INFO: FacesConfigurator:339 - MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox not found.
INFO: FacesConfigurator:339 - MyFaces-package : tomahawk not found.

If i take the jars out of the war and put them into the domain's lib directory for the system classpath then all works fine and the startup log shows:

INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-api in version : 1.2.2 from path : file:/C:/weblogic/user_projects/domains/testDomain/lib/myfaces-api-1.2.2.jar
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-impl in version : 1.2.2 from path : file:/C:/weblogic/user_projects/domains/testDomain/lib/myfaces-impl-1.2.2.jar
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox not found.
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : tomahawk in version : 1.1.6 from path : file:/C:/weblogic/user_projects/domains/testDomain/lib/tomahawk-1.1.6.jar

I would like to have this deployed as a shared library war in weblogic... so the question is how can i get the myfaces jars to be recognized when packed in a war file?

Comment: Can you try adding prefer-web-inf-classes to weblogic.xml? [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375185/class-cast-exception-in-weblogic/13375555#13375555)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source for org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator it showed that it will only look at paths that start with jar: and this explains why the myfaces jars are found when deployed either in the form of a custom weblogic module or in the domains lib folder.

When deployed in a war file (zip) the path starts with zip: and is overlooked. So as a test I recompiled and repackaged the org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator source after adding paths that start with zip: as a viable location to check and the jars were found. Here is the output on server startup after doing that change:

org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator:511) - Reading config **zip:**C:/weblogic/user_projects/domains/testDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/jsf-myfaces/x3xrze/WEB-INF/lib/tomahawk-1.1.6.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator:570) - Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator:333) - Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-api in version : 1.2.2 from path : C:/weblogic/user_projects/domains/testDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/jsf-myfaces/x3xrze/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-api-1.2.2.jar
org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator:333) - Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-impl in version : 1.2.2 from path : C:/weblogic/user_projects/domains/testDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/jsf-myfaces/x3xrze/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-1.2.2.jar

Important to note is that the 'myfaces api not found' log statement is not critical in any way... it's simply an INFO level log and it can be ignored.